# Changing OS X command line language

Tags: macos, command-line, internationalization, language

On Debian I managed to change it using `dpkg` and now UNIX commands, manual pages and supported packages are in my native language. Is there a way to do this also on OS X? I already have the locales set to my native language but everything is still english.

Comment: I am curious what package you actually installed via dpkg and what language it gave you.

Comment: @TomGewecke For example `ls --help` or `nano` are entirely translated. I am italian.

Answer (score 5):

Terminal and iTerm set LANG based on the region selected in System Preferences (`defaults read -g AppleLocale`) by default. It affects error messages and (some) help messages shown by bash, but not the language used by nano or for man pages.

```
$ export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
$ ashuhuf
-bash: ashuhuf: Kommando nicht gefunden.
$ help unalias
unalias: unalias [-a] Name [Name ...]
    Entferne jeden Namen von der Aliasliste.

    Optionen:
      -a    Enferne alle Alias Definitionen.

    Gibt immer Erfolg zurück, wenn der Name existiert.
```

Adding something like `export LANG=de_DE.UTF-8` to a configuration file like .bash_profile would have the same effect. I don't know any way to make the shell environment more localized though.

If others were searching for how to make Terminal or iTerm use English, add for example `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` to .bash_profile. Disabling setting locale variables automatically would make shells use the default C locale, which makes working with non-ASCII characters difficult at least in bash and other programs that use readline.

Comment: Using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` I was able to switch the language in existing installed packages. No need to reinstall anything. Is there something similar?

Comment: I don't think that setting `LANG` in `.bash_profile` will make Terminal or iTerm use the specified language. That setting will only apply to the shell and programs run from the shell.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I could've phrased it better, but I meant like bash (or other shells or programs that inherit the shell's environment) in Terminal or iTerm.