Cannot change terminal language despite doing everything seemingly correctly, GUI is translated
Happening on macOS: 14.4.1
I can't change through the GUI as this is required to be done for several languages and needs to be automated, the different locales will be in a script.
Everything I tried so far - GUI translated, Terminal is not
Here are the commands I ran to change the GUI to French (only first 2 are needed).
These are overkill as I was trying to get the terminal to translate:
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences AppleLanguages -array fr-FR
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences AppleLocale -string fr_FR
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences Country -string FR


sudo defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences AppleLanguages -array fr-FR
sudo defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences AppleLocale -string fr_FR
sudo defaults write ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences Country -string FR

Then I rebooted the machine, on checking the locale I get en_GB:
defaults read -g AppleLocale
en_GB 

However the file the command above supposedly reads shows fr_FR:
defaults read /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences AppleLocale
fr_FR

Language is also shown as fr-FR:
defaults read /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences AppleLanguages
{
    "fr-FR"
}

The outputs are the same for .GlobalPreferences in ~/Library.
I then tried to export these vars to ~/.zshrc which solved the problem for others:
cat ~/.zshrc

# tried this before to no avail, other answers said to use the uncommented LANG variable
# export LANG='fr_FR' 
export LANG='fr_FR.UTF-8'
export LC_ALL='fr_FR.UTF-8'

locale

locale
LANG="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="fr_FR.UTF-8"

Example to show terminal is still in English (the error text should be translated):
ls fged

ls: fged: No such file or directory

System Preferences shows français. Any ideas?

You are indeed doing everything right, but the French translation for the ls messages is missing, that's why they are displayed in English. In fact, the French translation is missing for all commands, as a quick look at /usr/share/locale/fr_FR.ISO8859-1/LC_MESSAGES/ will shown you (the UTF-8 directory is symlinked to the ISO8859-1 one), which is a shame. This question  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/384388/how-to-add-a-new-locale-to-macos-catalina describes a different but similar problem. You may want to try copying the message catalog files (.mo) files from Linux to  ...

... some directory of your choosing and setting PATH_LOCALE to point to that directory, but that will only work for GNU software, and most of the command line tools included with macOS are not. You could install GNU versions of popular commands like grep, sed, awk or even ls with brew, but you may lose functionality specific to macOS.

ah see the reason I need my terminal translated is because we are testing an app which should output a translated message based on the system locale, when I do defaults read -g it outputs en_gb for some reason despite the .GlobalPreference.plist file showing fr_FR... It makes no sense, everything is translated (the whole GUI), except the terminal, even on shutdown and login it doesn't translate

I have solved this problem will write an answer

For GUI translation and localisation all you need are these commands:
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences AppleLanguages -array ${lang}_${country}
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences AppleLocale -array ${lang}-${country}

# also this one for timezone (I needed it) 
# redirection because it errors for no reason, thanks to Linc for pointing that out

sudo systemsetup -settimezone $timeZone > /dev/null 2>&1

Now in the Terminal when you execute sudo defaults read -g <AppleLanguage>|<AppleLocale> it will output your previously set ones.

This is the case even if you updated the global and user plist files
This didn't make any sense to me as sudo defaults read -g <AppleLanguage>|<AppleLocale> should read from (or so I thought) /Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
This can be confirmed by running   sudo defaults read -g <AppleLanguage>|<AppleLocale>
So to update the global settings for these you have to run

sudo defaults write -g AppleLocale ${lang}_${country}
sudo defaults write -g AppleLanguage ${lang}-${country}


This won't translate the terminal because of the limitations of macOS, but it was important in my case for apps to translate their messages based on the language and locale set; with either missing I got strange characters in my message
I just came from doing this for linux so thought it was necessary to translate the whole terminal
Seems that this has been the case since apple dropped GNU locales there is an answer from 11 yrs ago in a comment I posted which shows this


macOS is not GNU. Most included shell commands are not localized. The only exceptions that I know of are CUPS commands such as lpstat(1). Otherwise, if you want shell locales, you'll have to install GNU stuff yourself.

I used all Mac commands to try to change the Mac terminal to French, why didn't it work? I seen posts of other people just exporting those variables for their Mac terminals and it worked. Or how to change the Mac terminal to French?

Please link to an example of the posts you saw.

have a look at this one: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96131/changing-os-x-command-line-language I tried the exact same de export and the command and got english output also in bash shell just like the answer

That was a long time ago. It's not supported now. Nevertheless, there may be some shell programs that have localizations. I gave an example. I don't have a complete list.
